# Eclipse IDE lost popup menu suggestions

Tags: eclipse

I've seem to have lost the ability in my Eclipse to auto-correct errors in my source code lines.

For example, a line like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

has red jagged lines beneath the Date() part. Previously I could mouse hover over it see a popup menu of options to fix it. Now I all I ever get is a popup with the text "Cannot resolve to a type".

The only change I can think of that I've made and I don't know if it has anything to do with this problem, is that I started editing my .java files with an outside editor. Then focusing back into Eclipse I get a popup saying the source has changed and do I want to update so I say OK.

Sometimes I will edit inside Eclipse and sometimes i will edit the source outside of Eclipse. I'm not sure if this is a bad practice or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your wish to edit Java files outside or inside eclipse. But Java editor has many features which are very helpful to developers. I suggest to edit Java files inside eclipse only.If you find other editors are good or you used to it then no problem you can edit Java files out side eclipse also. The problem you mentioned in not related to it. But make sure that changes are applied before building project in eclipse.

### Solution

This occurs whenever there are multiple classes are available with the same name in you build path then eclipse don't know which one to import by default. So keep the caret on the error line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. Then a eclipse gives options to user to import one among these. See the picture below. Choose the right one then error will disappear.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...I get "No suggestions available" !! On line Date date = new Date();